# Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. Error: a secret should be set

Tags: reactjs

I'm following a course to make an e-commerce website and when I try to sign a user up, I receive this error:
[image]
The instructor cloned my repo and received no errors however I am receiving an error whenever I try to sign up or sign in.

How can I solve this? Any help would be really appreciated.
Perhaps there's an issue with the errorHandler file that I'm using to handle the error.

controllers/auth.js

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken') // to generate signed token
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt') // for authorization check
const { errorHandler } = require('../helpers/dbErrorHandler')

exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    console.log("req.body", req.body)
    // signs up new user
 const user = new User(req.body)
 user.save((err, user) => {
if(err) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        err: errorHandler(err)
    })
}
user.salt = undefined 
user.hashed_password = undefined

res.json({
    user 
 })
 })
}

exports.signin = (req, res) => {
// find user based on email
const { email, password } = req.body 
User.findOne({email}, (err, user) => {
if (err || !user) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'User with that email does not exist.'
    })
}
// if user is found, ensure email & password match
// create authenticate method in user model
if (!user.authenticate(password)) {
    return res.status(401).json({
error: 'Email and password dont match'
    })
}
// generate signed token with user id and secret
const token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET)

// persist token as 't' in cookie with expiry date
res.cookie('t', token, {expire: new Date() + 9999 })

// return response with user & token to frontend client
const {_id, name, email, role} = user
return res.json({token, user: {_id, email, name, role}})
})
}

exports.signout = (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('t')
    res.json({ message: "Signout success" })
}

exports.requireSignin = expressJwt({
secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
userProperty: 'auth'
})

exports.isAuth = (req, res, next) => {
    let user = req.profile && req.auth && req.profile._id == req.auth._id
if(!user) {
    return res.status(403).json({
        error: "Access denied"
    })
}
    next()
}

exports.isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.profile.role === 0) {
        return res.status(403).json({
        error: 'Admin resource! Access denied'
        })
    }
    next()
}
```

The error message in the console:

```
  throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

Comment: it seems like you should catch that error instead of reading the data.error property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have uncaught exceptions in Components `Signup`  and `Signin`.

```
// Signin.js
const clickSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setValues({ ...values, error: false, loading: true })
    signin({ email, password }).then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, loading: false })
        } else {
            authenticate(data, () => {
                setValues({
                    ...values,
                    redirectToReferrer: true
                })
            })
        }
    }).catch(exc => {
        console.error("+++ exc signin: ", exc)
        // we log error 
        setValues({ ...values, error: exc.message, loading: false })
    });
}



// Signup.js
const clickSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setValues({ ...values, error: false });
    signup({ name, email, password }).then(data => {
        console.log("++ data: ", data);

        // if you need to check error from backend
        // else all exceptions are captured in catch block 
        if (data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, success: false });
        } else {
            setValues({
                ...values,
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                error: '',
                success: true
            });
        }
    }).catch(exc => {
        console.error('++ exc: ', exc);

        setValues({ ...values, error: exc.message, success: false });
    })
};
```

Then in `auth/index.js`, only return fetch promise and let calling function handle exception.

```
 // cors mode to allow cross-origin 
 export const signup = (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })

};



// mode cors to allow cross-origin access
export const signin = (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signin`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
        .then(response => {
            return response.json()
        })

}
```

On backend end, make sure these keys are set process.env.JWT_SECRET or you can either use a default value in case key is not set or exit app on startup if important keys are not set.

process.env.JWT_SECRET || 'default_ket'

You need to create .env file at root of ecommerce-back and in it

```
DATABASE=mongodb://localhost:27017/Ecommerce
JWT_SECRET=secret
```

Here, it is Mongo is running on default port and your database name is Ecommerce, otherwise set values according to your setup.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried everything you mentioned however I'm still receiving the cross-origin error in the browser and I am now receiving a different error in the console:   ```throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^
Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.``` @artfulbeest

Comment: Check updated answer, it solve cors issue and I have Mongo error @Rahni

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has solved the cors issue and I can finally access the application without an error. I can also sign up without any errors however the issue is that every time I sign in, I receive the error that I had set up: ```User with that email does not exist``` despite using the correct emails. @artfulbeest

Comment: Can you log request body on the backend side to see if email being sent is the one entered in form?

Comment: I've just seen that I'm actually receiving a 404 error when I sign up too despite the "New account has been created. Sign in" message showing. This is the output in the terminal when I sign up: ```OPTIONS /api/signup 204 0.328 ms - 0
req.body { name: 'xhui', email: 'joisk@gmail.com', password: 'dhubj678' }
POST /api/signup 400 12.230 ms - 30```. @artfulbeest

Comment: It seems your signup request isn't passing some validations.Try to log response in Signup.clickSubmit to see error messages being returned

Comment: It has finally worked. I cloned my repo again and made all the changes in your answer. I also changed the database name to lowercase e in .env file and everything is working. Thank you for your help!!@artfulbeest

Answer (score 0):

You can use an optional chaining operator to check the truthiness of `data.error` such that if `data` is `undefined` or `null`, the statement will evaluate to `false` and you'll continue to the `else` block:

```
if(data?.error) {
    setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false})
} else { ... }
```

Or you can go old-school and check for `data` and `data.error` separately:

```
if(data && data.error) {
    setValues({...values, error: data.error, loading: false})
} else { ... }
```

As for the `Error: secret should be set`, you should set your secret in your `.env` file, like you did with `REACT_APP_API_URL`. It looks like you might need to do the same with `DATABASE` and `PORT`, unless you plan on making these runtime parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried all of this however I am still receiving the `Error: secret should be set` and I'm now receiving a different error in the browser: `Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. `  @Bucket